What is the probability that the absolute value of the roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ is greater than $x$?
Note: Posted in MO since it is unanswered in MSE.
Let $f(x) = 0$ be an equation of degree $n$. WLOG we can assume that the its coefficients are in $(-1,1)$. This is because we can divide each coefficient by the coefficient with the largest magnitude to make each one of them fall in the interval $(-1,1)$.
Assume that the coefficients are uniformly random in $(-1,1)$. It is well known that most of absolute values of the roots have value close to one i.e. the roots tend to form a unit circle around the origin as shown in the figure below for a polynomial of degree $n = 666$.

It can be observed from the graph that while most of the roots are close to the unit circle, some of them are outside it. I want to find the probability $P(n,x)$that a roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ lies at a distance $x > 1$ from the origin. To do this, I run a simulation generating polynomial of degree $n$ and its $n$ roots in each trial and counted the total number of roots across all the trials whose absolute value is $\ge x$.

Question: Experimental data shows that $P(n,1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and for $x > 1$, $\displaystyle n P(n,x) \to  \frac{1}{2x}$ as $n \to \infty$. Can this be proved or disproved?

Related: Is the root of a polynomial with the largest modulus more likely to be real?

Slightly related

When you say "probability P(n,x)
that a root of a polynomial of degree n
lies at a distance x>1", wouldn't it be more precise to say "probability P(n,x) for a polynomial of degree n
that the modulus m  of its root with greatest modulus verifies $m>x$" ?
"

Related: Why do roots of polynomials tend to have absolute value close to $1$?

See this blog who uses the classical transformation roots of a polynomial $\leftrightarrow$ eigenvalues of its companion matrix.

Do you really mean $nP(n,x)$ and not $P(n,x)$?

@GregMartin Yes correct I meant $nP(n,x)$. I observed that as $n$ increases, the density of roots near the unit circle increases so roots at a distance $x>1$ decreased inversely with both $n$ and $x$.
